# Смещение курсора при использовании ace.js

Tags: jquery, ace

Подскажите, при использовании ace.js (редактор кода) если поместить текст с ударением и в конце текста начать печатать, то курсор некорректно смещается.
Как это поправить?
https://jsfiddle.net/5vkjudrw/

```js
var editor = ace.edit('editor', {
        mode: "ace/mode/html",
        selectionStyle: "text",
        autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
        minLines: 1,
        maxLines: 2000
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/mode-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/ace.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor" class="editor">Я занима́юсь про́граммированием</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня такая заплатка. Двумя вариантами использования [символов](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/letters/)

```js
var editor = ace.edit('editor', {
        mode: "ace/mode/html",
        selectionStyle: "text",
        autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
        minLines: 1,
        maxLines: 2000
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/mode-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.11/ace.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor" class="editor">Я заним&#225;юсь пр&oacute;граммированием</div>
```